# Method not defined in model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, methods

I'm getting undefined method in my model but I believe I have it.

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id, :name, :city, :state, :zip, :street, :latitude, :longitude

  def new_address
    [street, city, state, zip].join(', ')
  end  
  geocoded_by :new_address
  after_validation :geocode, :if => :new_address_changed?

end
```

I'm getting the undefined method error on `new_address_changed?` Is this wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*_changed?` methods are available only for active record attributes and not for user defined methods. For you, `street_changed?` etc will work.

The best way out is to define another method like so:

```
def address_changed?
  street_changed? || city_changed? || state_changed? || zip_changed?
end
```

Comment: Ohhh, what would the alternative be if the `new_address` changes?

Comment: Well, you will have to define `address_changed?` method yourself, and check for individual field changes in there.

Answer (score 2):

you can define `method` by your own, as `new_address` is not `active_record` attribute:

```
def new_address_changed?
  street_changed? || city_changed? || state_changed? || zip_changed?
end
```